# C - non-standard struct "compatibility"

Tags: c, struct, casting, undefined-behavior

In short, my question is thus:

the C standard explicitly states that struct members should have relative addresses that grow in the order they are declared. It also does not state any detail whatsoever on how exactly the struct members should be aligned. This was, obviously, done to allow for both padded- and packed-struct implementations. However, theoretically, there can be a standard-conforming compiler that would give the struct members totally random addresses as long as they grow in the same order as the members are declared. But does such a compiler exist?

Here's some detail. Consider the following two structs:

```
struct s1 {
    int var1;
    char var2;
    long var3;
};

struct s2 {
    int var1;
    char var2;
    long var3;
    char var4;
    int var5;
};
```

and the following code:

```
printf("offsetof(struct s1, var2) = %d\n", 
        offsetof(struct s1, var2));

printf("offsetof(struct s2, var2) = %d\n", 
        offsetof(struct s2, var2));

printf("offsetof(struct s1, var3) = %d\n", 
        offsetof(struct s1, var3));

printf("offsetof(struct s2, var3) = %d\n", 
        offsetof(struct s2, var3));
```

**gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911** produces the following output:

```
offsetof(struct s1, var2) = 4                                                 
offsetof(struct s2, var2) = 4                                                 
offsetof(struct s1, var3) = 8                                                 
offsetof(struct s2, var3) = 8
```

This makes perfect sense: a regular standard-conforming compiler (one that does not reorder struct members), when performing padding for a struct member, takes into account only the size and offset of the previous struct member. This means that the relative addresses of the first members of two structs that have corresponding types will always be the same on such compilers. Which, in turn, means that in our example, we could safely do the following:

```
struct s2 test_s2, *ptest_s2;
struct s1 test_s1, *ptest_s1;

ptest_s2 = &test_s2;
ptest_s1 = &test_s1;

ptest_s2->var1 = 1;
ptest_s2->var2 = '2';

ptest_s1 = (struct s1*)ptest_s2;

printf("ptest_s1->var1 = %d\n", ptest_s1->var1);
printf("ptest_s1->var2 = %c\n", ptest_s1->var2);
```

Which compiles and runs fine and gives, on the same compiler, the output

```
ptest_s1->var1 = 1                                                            
ptest_s1->var2 = 2
```

As all pointers to structs have the same representation and alignment by the standard, the only source of UB here is actually expecting that the relative addresses of the first struct members that have corresponding types will be the same in the two structs.

Now, here's the actual question: are there any real-world compilers (those that do NOT reorder struct members) where the relative addresses can be different?

**P.S.** I know that in C11, I could get exactly the same results in a well-defined way by replacing the first struct's members in the second struct by an anonymous instance of the first struct (which, by the way, as I understand, should internally work in the same fashion), but I want to write code that could do the same on compiler versions that do not support anonymous structs.

Comment: Probably offtopic as it is opinion based/ too broad. As you ask "Exists something sense less? And if so, what moved the developer to do something senseless?"

Comment: I would say 'on topic' - 'does such a compiler exist' amounts to 'is this logic portable'.

Comment: @Zaibis: I removed the part of the question about reasons for the existence of such potential implementations. I asked this out of pure curiosity, but this could really make my question sound opinion-based. Sorry.

Comment: What does not exist today may well exist tomorrow, and become mainstream next week. Are you planning to ask this question every day? Sticking with the standard is easier.

Comment: @Dan Allen: Than off topic, as asking for a off site tool, what a compiler simply is.

Comment: @Mints97: Don't get me wrong. The question is in my eyes also interesting. You invested time for the example and explanation. And I would like to hear also about the reasons for such implementation. But I can't really see a technical aspect in the question that makes it on topic. But well, as long no one else thinks so, thats no problem. ^^

Comment: @zaibis I would say 'is the following portable' is nearly always on topic.

Comment: Sorry but perhaps I'm too old... what is offsetof?  I have seen a lot of macro definitions to calculate the right offset of a pointer to a field in a structure, but never seen support from the language.  Have you defined offsetof somewhere? is it a specific compiler feature?  what happens when you don't have offsetof and alignment issues in the compiler you use?

Comment: If offsetof is something defined in c11, for sure there will be other features to control the packing of fields in a structure or to control de placement at low level.  Or not?

Comment: @LuisColorado: it's a macro that has been part of the standard since C89, it's defined in stddef.h (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof)

Comment: @Mints97 I have seen a lot of these macros defined and it's perfectly clear what it means. Thanks :) The question was a tricky one, as one compiler that assigns completely random offsets to the struct fields is by no means adding a doubtfull feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question comes up more than you might think. 
As far as I can tell the answer is a qualified 'no'.

The consensus appears to be that compilers have no real reason to pad members other than to ensure they are properly aligned to their start and can occupying consecutive locations in an array.

The standard requires the first member to be at the start of the `struct`.

I can only find people (on here, the web, etc.) who believe that the following is the most portable known way to determine the alignment of type T and no one has ever offered an incompatible platform.

```
#include<stddef.h>

#define alignment(T) (offsetof(struct {char w;T v;},v))
```

Compiler developers don't tend to waste memory for no good reason. However it's theoretically possible that (say) someone could decide to place an unaligned member at the end of an area of padding rather than the start. 
It's even conceivable that a debugging compiler could add 'overwrite sentinels' at the ends of array types.

However I can find no specimen (or claim of) a compiler that (when not packing data) does anything other than start with the first member, pad up minimally for the next member then end pad for the strictest aligned member.

However different compilers even on a single architecture might make different decisions about primitive types so one `struct` may have a different layout even on the same hardware architecture.

So you can't rely on this for inter-operability.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct s3 {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
};

struct s4 {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int var3;
    long long var4;
};
```

When you add a type with stronger alignment requirement, then you change the alignment of the whole struct.

Then when you cast and dereference the pointer, then it's UB.

In the code above, I believe adding a `var4` at the end will change `var1` from word-aligned to double-word aligned, assuming `int` is word-aligned and `long long` is double-word aligned.

`long` is a very bad example because it's 32 bits in 32-bit gcc but 64 bits in 64-bit gcc.